# Jenkins Multiple SCM Branch Selection

Tags: jenkins, version-control

I want a jenkins job with multiple GIT projects. I want to select a particular GIT project and based on that I should be able to select the branch(similar to GIT plugin) to build.

Any plugins or other solutions to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct plugin solution for this. Previously we can do it using [Multiple SCMs Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multiple+SCMs+Plugin). But as of now, only one solution is using `pipeline` scripting, because that plugin is deprecated.

So, now you can do that by [Jenkins Pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/) Scripts. You can see [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40224272/using-a-jenkins-pipeline-to-checkout-multiple-git-repos-into-same-job/40225216) for further pipeline multi git scripting.

Comment: Ok Thanks.. i will look into that

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding a shell command (as a build step) that does an "old fashioned" git clone:

```
    git clone https://$bitbucketUsername:$bitbucketPassword@<yourBitbucketServer>.com/scm/projectname/reponame1.git
    git clone https://$bitbucketUsername:$bitbucketPassword@<yourBitbucketServer>.com/scm/projectname/reponame2.git
```