# How to refer to multiple repositories in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

When creating a new item in Jenkins (Freestyle), one can choose more than one Git repositories under "Source Code Management".

I want to create a post-build action to archive files from two repositories as artifacts. I clicked on "Advanced..." on each repo in order to give each repo a name, but still when I check the workspace I see only the latest repo there.

Any tips on how can I see both repos on the workspace?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's recommended to switch to Pipeline Project inside of Freestyle to support check out sources from multiple SCM providers ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40225216/6364177)). Otherwise, if you keep using Freestyle project you can use this plugin [Multiple SCMs Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/multiple-scms/).

Comment: Thanks Houssam. But I wonder why is it so that one can add multiple repos on the freestyle, if one cannot reach them.

Comment: It's normal because your SCMs work in the same directory. In "Source Code Management" and under each Repo click on "Additional Behaviors" and choose "Check out to a sub-directory" and provide a name of each sub-directory.