# How to tell Jenkins about multiple SCM via Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

To build my project, I need to pull 3 git repositories.

In the stage view, I only see the commits from 1 of those 3 git repositories.

[image: Screenshot Jenkins Stage View]

How can I tell Jenkins about the other 2 repos?

Comment: PLS check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37395860/jenkinsfile-with-two-git-repositories

Comment: Yep, this works. But unfortunately, there is no information which commit goes to which repo.

Answer (score 3):

I think that if you're using a Pipeline job then the suggestion from @Mor Lajb is working properly. You can basically specify the three git sources directly from the pipeline Groovy script.

Conversely, if you're using a multi-branch pipeline job then you probably need to select 'configure' from within your project and under 'branch sources' add as many git sources you need (use add source button).