# How to use multiple docker repositories in a Jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline in which I need to log into two different docker repositories. I know how to authenticate to one repo using the following command

```
docker.withRegistry('https://registry.example.com', 'credentials-id')
```

but don't know how to do it for more than 1 repo?

Comment: You can switch between the two at different points in your pipeline.

Comment: could you elaborate how with example?

Comment: Similar situations answered: [Using a Jenkins pipeline to checkout multiple git repos into same job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40224272/using-a-jenkins-pipeline-to-checkout-multiple-git-repos-into-same-job) [Jenkinsfile with two git repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37395860/jenkinsfile-with-two-git-repositories)

Comment: He wants to pull content from two docker registries while doing the docker build. (Note that this has nothing to do with two git repositories)

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 6):

Nesting `docker.withRegistry` calls actually works as expected. Each call adds an entry to `/home/jenkins/.dockercfg` with provided credentials.

```
// Empty registry ('') means default Docker Hub `https://index.docker.io/v1/`
docker.withRegistry('', 'dockerhub-credentials-id') {
  docker.withRegistry('https://private-registry.example.com', 'private-credentials-id') {
    // your build steps ...
  }
}
```

This allows you to pull base images from Docker Hub using provided credentials to avoid recently introduced pull limits, and push results into another docker registry.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore, the call to withRegistry creates a temporary docker configuration file that changes with each call.

E.g., "WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /home/ubuntu/workspace/test@tmp/af4e4211-ee8e-4510-9efe-734d6329990d/config.json."

https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-58837

Comment: if this does not work as @RyanD says, what should be the recommended way to do it?

Answer (score 4):

While the other answers give some nice options for using scripted pipeline syntax to run multiple docker repositories, there is also built in support for declarative syntax.
Jenkins declarative [pipeline syntax](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#agent) supports both running a job on a docker agent taken from a custom registry (repository), or using a dynamically built dockerfile that can be based on images from a custom registry.

Here is some more info on the two options:

1. **Docker agent**

> Execute the Pipeline, or stage, with the given container which will be dynamically provisioned on a node pre-configured to accept Docker-based Pipelines, or on a node matching the optionally defined label parameter.
> docker also optionally accepts a registryUrl and registryCredentialsId parameters which will help to specify the Docker Registry to use and its credentials. The parameter registryCredentialsId could be used alone for private repositories within the docker hub. For example:

```groovy
agent {
    docker {
        image 'myregistry.com/node'
        label 'my-defined-label'
        registryUrl 'https://myregistry.com/'
        registryCredentialsId 'myPredefinedCredentialsInJenkins'
    }
}
```

2. **dockerfile**

> Execute the Pipeline, or stage, with a container built from a Dockerfile contained in the source repository. In order to use this option, the Jenkinsfile must be loaded from either a Multibranch Pipeline or a Pipeline from SCM.
> dockerfile also optionally accepts a registryUrl and registryCredentialsId parameters which will help to specify the Docker Registry to use and its credentials. For example:

```groovy
agent {
    dockerfile {
        filename 'Dockerfile.build'
        dir 'build'
        label 'my-defined-label'
        registryUrl 'https://myregistry.com/'
        registryCredentialsId 'myPredefinedCredentialsInJenkins'
    }
}
```

You can than use both of these options per stage, which means using a differently image and registry per stage:

```groovy
pipeline {
   stages {
      stage('First') {
         agent {
            docker {
               ...  // First registry
            }
         }
         steps {
            ...
         }
      }
      stage('Second') {
         agent {
            docker {
               ...  // Second registry
            }
         }
         steps {
            ...
         }
      }
   }
}
```

If needed the decelerative syntax can be combined with the scripted syntax by using a `script` block inside one of the stages, in which the scripted syntax can be used. For example:

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'myregistry.com/node'
            registryUrl 'https://myregistry.com/'
            registryCredentialsId 'myPredefinedCredentialsInJenkins'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage("Build") {
            steps {
                script {
                    echo 'Using custom registry https://myregistry2.com/'
                    docker.withRegistry('https://myregistry2.com/', 'myPredefinedCredentialsInJenkins2') {
                        // Use the second registry here
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

---

---

If all the built in methods are not working for you as expected, you can always create an implementation of your own, and use it across your pipeline via a shared library.
For example you can create the following shared lib method in a **useDockerRegistry.groovy** file:

```groovy
def call(String registry, String credentialsId, Closure body) {
    println "Log in to ${registry}"
    withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'credentialsId', usernameVariable: 'DOCKER_USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'DOCKER_PASSWORD')]) {
        sh "docker login -u \$DOCKER_USERNAME -p \$DOCKER_PASSWORD ${registry}"
    }
    try {
        body()
    }
    finally {
        println "Log out from ${registry}"
        sh "docker logout ${registry}"     // clean up the session
    }
}
```

Then in your pipelines you can use it for a single registry or for multiple nested ones.
For Example:

```groovy
library "myLib"

pipeline {
   agent any
   stages {
      stage('Single Registry') { 
         steps {
            useDockerRegistry('https://myregistry.com/', 'registryCredentials') {
               ... // code using myregistry
            }
         }
      }
      stage('Multiple Registries') {
         steps {
            useDockerRegistry('https://myregistry.com/', 'registryCredentials') {
                useDockerRegistry('https://myregistry2.com/', 'registry2Credentials') {
                ... // code using myregistry & myregistry2
                }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

You can nest as many useDockerRegistry calls as you want.
In addition you can easily modify the logic of the function according to your needs.

Answer (score 2):

This is a partial answer only applicable when you are using two registries but only need credentials on one. You can nest the calls since they mostly just do a docker login that stays active for the scope of the closure and will add the registry domain name into docker pushes and such.

Use this in a scripted Jenkins pipeline or in a script { } section of a declarative Jenkins pipeline:

```
docker.withRegistry('https://registry.example1.com') { // no credentials here
    docker.withRegistry('https://registry.example2.com', 'credentials-id') { // credentials needed
        def container = docker.build('myImage')
        container.inside() {
            sh "ls -al" // example to run on the newly built 
        }
    }
}
```

Sometimes you can use two, non-nested calls to docker.withRegistry() one after the other but building is an example of when you can't if, for example, the base image for the first FROM in the Dockerfile needs one registry and the base image for a second FROM is in another registry.

Answer (score -1):

Following is a Jenkins pipeline for using multiple docker repositories, authenticating, building and pushing them.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    
    environment {
        DOCKER_REGISTRY_1 = 'https://first.registry.com'
        DOCKER_REGISTRY_2 = 'https://second.registry.com'
        CREDENTIALS_ID_1 = 'credentials-id-1'
        CREDENTIALS_ID_2 = 'credentials-id-2'
    }

    stages {
        stage('Build and Push Image to Registry 1') {
            steps {
                script {
                    // Authenticate with the first Docker registry
                    docker.withRegistry(DOCKER_REGISTRY_1, CREDENTIALS_ID_1) {
                        // Build and push your Docker image to the first registry
                        docker.build('your-image-name:tag').push()
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Build and Push Image to Registry 2') {
            steps {
                script {
                    // Authenticate with the second Docker registry
                    docker.withRegistry(DOCKER_REGISTRY_2, CREDENTIALS_ID_2) {
                        // Build and push your Docker image to the second registry
                        docker.build('your-image-name:tag').push()
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Add more stages if required
    }
}
```

Using the above pipeline should fix the issue for you.