# Run tests written in different language as part of one Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins

I have E2E tests written in golang and java for my application.

I want to kick off all E2E tests together as part of one Jenkins job. Is it doable?

Comment: Yrs, justv un in two steps. Catch is 2nd step won't run if the first fails, unless you use a pipeline and [try/catch the failure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56975220/598141)

Comment: Can one Jenkins job run tests from 2 different repository?

Comment: You can clone pull from multiple repos, but the UI only supports multiple same repos (ie:common ancestor). To clone/pull feom multiple distinct repos, you need to use [pipelines](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37395860/598141)